# How do I prove that the sign of the discriminant $d_K \in \mathbb{Z}$ of K is $(−1)^{r_2}$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

we have the following exercise in our course and I really do not know how to solve this.

Let K be a number field and write, $r_1$ for the number of its real embeddings
and $2r_2$ for the number of its complex (non-real) embeddings. Prove that the sign of
the discriminant $d_K \in \mathbb{Z}$ of K is $(−1)^{r_2}$.

I do not know how to start, do you have any idea?

Comment: Note that $r_2\equiv \frac{n(n-1)}{2}+\frac{r_1(r_1-1)}{2}\bmod 2$ where the RHS is what shows up when looking at $Disc(f)=(-1)^{n(n-1)/2}\prod_{i\ne j} (\alpha_i-\alpha_j)$ separating the pairs with both $\alpha_i,\alpha_j\in \Bbb{R}$ from the others.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much!